# Use Tex expression in R `main` label

Tags: r

I'm plotting a histogram in R and I want to include a $\bar{X}$ expression in the `main` argument of `hist` and combine it with the value of a dynamically calculated variable `average`.

```
x <- rnorm(100, 1, 1)
average <- mean(x)
hist(x, main=paste("Average $\bar{X}=", average))
```

That SO doesn't work and I spent hours trying to get it working with an `expression` statement or a `substitute` statement, both of which I dont find a case in the examples where the value of a variable is substituted in the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
hist(x, main=bquote(Average~bar(X)==.(average) )
```

`bquote`'s main use is to "import-and-evaluate" named values from the global (or enclosing) environment(s) into an expression which would otherwise not be evaluating its tokens. You could add spaces to make the expression more readable but the parser ignores them:

```
 hist(x, main=bquote( Average ~ bar(X) == .( average ) )
```

If you need extra spaces use multiple tilde's: `~~~`

It's rather interesting to look at the code for bquote (easy since it's not hidden):

```
bquote
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `*` to paste text and expressions and uses `substitute` to replace 'average' with the calculated value.

```
hist(x, main = substitute("Average "*bar(x)*" = "*average, list(average=average)))
```

Comment: Somewhat more in the spirit of "full plotmath" would be: `substitute( Average ~ bar(x)==average, list( average=average ))`

Comment: Can you give me one line of explanation on that? Works, that's positive. What are we doing here: `list( average=average ))`?

Comment: Basically what happens is that the item on the right-side of the `average=average` gets evaluated, i.e. its numeric of character value gets looked up in the Global environment, and that value gets put into the first argument (an unevaluated expression) to `substitute`  wherever the left-side string appears.